# Solr ignoring slash order

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, solr4

I have an index field called: `texts`

The field contains values like: `12/1`

And also: `1/12`

The problem is when I query: `texts:"1/*"`

It's finding also `12/1` it's like the slash don't have any meaning.

How I can limit the results by order?

(I've tried `texts:"1\/*"` and it's not working)

The type of the field:

```
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the `TextField` type that performs tokenization of your text, and then additional filtering, like, lower-casing, etc.  In your case, you don't have value `12/1` in your index, but you have 2 values, `12` and `1`, for both first & second values, so you search for `1/*` will match to both records because search will be performed for value `1` that was generated after tokenization of your input.

To keep string from tokenization you need:

- either use `StrField` type instead - but in this case, the string will be indexed as-is, without lower-casing, etc.
- if you want to have lower-casing, etc., then define a new type for your field, but use `solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory` as tokenizer, and add corresponding filters.

You can read more in the [DataStax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/aboutFields.html). Also note, that starting with version 6, default type for `text` data is `StrField`, and you need explicitly define `TextField` if you need tokenization, etc.

Comment: I've changed the type to StrField (re-index everything) and now the "1/*" not working at all, I've also tried "1\/*", any idea why?

Comment: Sorry it's working, I was needed to remove the quotes, to only: 1/*